# Add a checkbox field inside the refund section in WooCommerce edit order

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I tried this code

```
function add_custom_checkbox_after_restock($order_id) {
    $order = wc_get_order($order_id);
    $restock_refunded_items = $order->get_meta('_restock_refunded_items', true);

    echo '<div class="edit-field">
            <label for="custom_checkbox">' . __('Custom Checkbox Label', 'your-theme-textdomain') . '</label>
            <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="custom_checkbox" id="custom_checkbox" value="1" ' . checked($restock_refunded_items, 'yes', false) . ' />
        </div>';
}
add_action('woocommerce_admin_order_totals_after_total', 'add_custom_checkbox_after_restock');
```

But the checkbox is displayed after Order Total:

[image]

But I would like to display it before "Restock refunded items":

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no available hook to insert your custom checkbox where you want. But with some jQuery code, you can get:

[image]

Here is the code:

```php
add_action( 'admin_footer', 'custom_order_filter_callback' );
function custom_order_filter_callback() {
    global $pagenow, $typenow, $post;

    if ( 'post.php' === $pagenow && 'shop_order' === $typenow ) :
        $meta_value = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_restock_refunded_items', true );
        $checked    = checked($meta_value, 'yes', false);

        $html  = '<tr class="edit-field"><td class="label">';
        $html .= '<label for="custom_checkbox">' . __('Custom Checkbox Label', 'woocommerce') . '</label></td>';
        $html .= '<td class="total"><input type="checkbox" name="custom_checkbox" id="custom_checkbox" value="1" ' . $checked . ' />';
        $html .= '</td><</div></td></tr>';
    ?>
    <script>
    jQuery(function($){
        $('.wc-order-refund-items .wc-order-totals tbody').prepend('<?php echo $html; ?>');
    });
    </script>
    <?php
    endif;
}
```